# Update an entry in the database from a single row in a table using a submit button cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a page that displays a table of people that have not been checked in yet and one of the columns in this table is a "process" button that when clicked should update their processed time in the database to the time of the click. How can I update each users processed time when their processed button is clicked without having to input any extra information? (if that is at all possible)

I have a controller called new_student_arrival_reservations that accesses a table in my database with the corresponding name (UsersNewStudentArrivalReservation). Here's the code for my table displaying the people that need to be processed.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
<thead>
    <tr><th>Name</th><th>ID</th><th>Program #</th><th>Residence Hall</th><th>Room Number</th><th>Process</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php foreach($newStudents as $id => $newStudent): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $newStudent['UsersNewStudentArrivalReservation']['student_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?= $newStudent['UsersNewStudentArrivalReservation']['student_id']; ;?></td>
            <td><?= $newStudent['UsersNewStudentArrivalReservation']['checkin_num']; ?></td>
            <td><?= $newStudent['UsersNewStudentArrivalReservation']['res_hall'];  ?></td>
            <td><?= $newStudent['UsersNewStudentArrivalReservation']['room_number'];  ?></td>
            <td>
                <button type="button">Process</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

The table displays perfectly and all of the information is correct. As previously stated, I would like the process button on each row to update that persons processed time.

Please let me know if any other information is needed. Thank You!

Comment: please specify your cake version